# How to verify with XUnit that method was called or was not called without Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have a class that has an update method. In the update method, I'm checking whether its properties are really changed.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public void UpdatePerson(Person person)
    {
        if (FirstName == person.FirstName && LastName == person.LastName) return;

        ApplyChanges(person);
    }

    public void ApplyChanges(Person person)
    {
        //....
    }

}
```

I need to ensure that `ApplyChanges` method is not called when `Person` properties are same.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a copy-paste, but I believe the [recommendation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices#validate-private-methods-by-unit-testing-public-methods) applies to your question:

> In most cases, there should not be a need to test a private method.
> Private methods are an implementation detail. You can think of it this
> way: private methods never exist in isolation. At some point, there is
> going to be a public facing method that calls the private method as
> part of its implementation. What you should care about is the end
> result of the public method that calls into the private one.

I suggest reading the link I provided in full detail.

Having said that, if you really think this private method needs to be tested, then that implies **that it should probably be moved to a separate class**. However, looking at your example, this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Mostly I'm interested if I can check a method execution without Moq. Now, I've changed ApplyChanges method to Public.

Comment: @K.Arjevanidze: If your question is "is it possible?" and do not care about best practices, you can use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method). However, doing that would be ignoring all the advice given from most programmers... Also, looking at your code, I see no reason why `ApplyChanges` should be tested at all.

Comment: thanks for your answer anyways.

Comment: Similar question was asked almost simultaneously here.. .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71652221/how-to-verify-that-a-method-of-a-sut-has-benn-called-- only difference is to verify the method was called instead of not called.